# Unable to display data from AJAX call JSON data with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Really puzzled by this so help would be great

Im trying to view JSON data from a job search API

Query Below ( access key had to be removed )

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "https://www.cv-library.co.uk/search-jobs-json?",
key: '',
query: 'Support',
geo: 'London',
distance: 200,
tempperm: ['Part Time', 'Permanent'].
success: function(data)
{
    console.log(data);

    $.each(data.results, function(i, val) {
        // here you can do your magic
        $("#joblist").append(document.createTextNode(val.title));
        $("#joblist").append(document.createTextNode(val.logo));
    });
}
```

});

Here is the data it should be returning

```
{
"jobs": [
   {
        "agency": {
            "title": "BCT Resourcing",
            "type": "Recruitment Agency",
            "url": "https://www.cv-library.co.uk/list-jobs/289229/BCT-Resourcing"
        },
        "applications": "<10",
        "description": "Position: Automation & Monitoring Engineers\nLocation: Hampshire\nSalary: \u00a340000- \u00a355000 Per Annum\nJob type: Permanent\n\nDescription\n Candidates must have lived in the UK for 5 years minimum in order to achieve the security clearance required for this role.\n \nOur client work with a number of exciting and often cutting-edge technologies in a fast-moving environment.  With this environment, great automation and monitoring delivers huge value in both pace and accuracy for our team and Customers, in turn increasing our capability.  Our team are responsible for the management platform, tools and systems to automate, manage and monitor infrastructure",
        "distance": 3,
        "hl_title": "Automation & Monitoring Engineers",
        "id": "205765440",
        "location": "Farnborough",
        "logo": "https://www.cv-library.co.uk/logo/big/bac0998768784a75beea9b928d5c8c89",
        "posted": "2017-04-26T10:31:27Z",
        "salary": "\u00a340000 - \u00a355000/annum",
        "title": "Automation & Monitoring Engineers",
        "type": [
            "Permanent"
        ],
        "url": "/job/205765440/Automation-Monitoring-Engineers?hlkw=Perl&s=101081"
    }
],
"total_entries": 13
```

But I get nothing..
Help would be great thanks in advance

Comment: I suppose that `key, query, geo, distance, tempperm` are parameters to pass to the `URL` ?

Comment: Yes although it only requires key & q to produce results

Comment: is it safe to assume that the `.` in `tempperm: ['Part Time', 'Permanent'].` is unintentional and is really a `,` in your source?

Comment: Next time you have trouble with an AJAX call, make sure to examine the structure of the _outgoing_ request as closely as you study the structure of the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass parameters to the `url`, you need to use the `data` parameter for the `$.ajax()` function.

From your `url`, it seems that the method used by the remote is `GET`, so this code should work :

```
var myData = encodeURIComponent("key=YourKey&query=Support&geo=London&distance=200&tempperm=Part Time");
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "https://www.cv-library.co.uk/search-jobs-json",
 data = myData,
 success: function(data)
 {
    console.log(data);

    $.each(data.results, function(i, val) {
        // here you can do your magic
        $("#joblist").append(document.createTextNode(val.title));
        $("#joblist").append(document.createTextNode(val.logo));
    });
 }

});
```

**Edit :**
From you comment below, the returned data is like this `{jobs: Array(25), total_entries: 220}`, so to loop the jobs, you need to do this :

```
$.each(data.jobs, function(i, val) {
    $("#joblist").append(document.createTextNode(val.agency.title));
    $("#joblist").append(document.createTextNode(val.logo));
});
```

Comment: this is strange because it shows the data in the console window
{jobs: Array(25), total_entries: 220}

Comment: You are doing `$.each(data.results` but the returned data does not contain any thing with the name `results`

Comment: I've edited the answer with a part to loop the jobs list. Hope it helps.

Comment: spotted it .. replaced results with jobs.. working great !
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try below. If you get same error, check that JSON is valid or invalid.

```
success: function(data) {
    var res = $.parseJSON(data);
    $.each(res.jobs, function(i, val) {
        $("#joblist").append(document.createTextNode(val.title));
        $("#joblist").append(document.createTextNode(val.logo));
    });
}
```